# why is this method of finding $A^2+3A$ wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which represents
$ 3i +3j+3k$
so the cross product of A with itself is $O$

so the answer is $3A$
however, my book says that the answer is $18A$

why am I wrong

Comment: What do you mean by "the cross-product of $A$ with itself"? You can take a cross-product between two vectors, but not between two matrices.

Comment: doesn't a matrix reprsent vectors though?

Comment: Are you aware of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem?

Comment: I think you need to review the cross product (which has no use in this question). Do the matrix multiplication.

Comment: @user170231,no, never heard of it

Comment: @SeanRoberson, will do. Thanks

Comment: The book's answer is wrong. It should be $6A$.

Comment: I see, thanks!!

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever In some contexts, a $3 \times 3$ matrix is used to represent a list of vectors; in this case, that list would be $(3i, 3j, 3k)$. However, there is no context in which $A$ would be used to represent the *single* vector $3i + 3j + 3k$.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, since $A=3I$ is a simple matrix, computing $A^2+3A$ is trivial.

$$A^2 + 3A = (3I)^2 + 3(3I) = 9I^2 + 9I = 18I = 6(3I) = 6A$$

By Cayley-Hamilton: using the characteristic polynomial of $A$ we have

$$p(\lambda) = (3-\lambda)^2 \implies p(A) = 9I - 6A + A^2 = 0$$

Add $9A-9I$ to both sides; it follows that

$$A^2 + 3A = 9A - 9I = 9A-3A = 6A$$

Comment: Thanks! But is there an way to solve this using vectors alone?

Comment: Well I suppose the matrix product can be decomposed into a matrix of dot products, but that seems like more work than necessary. For example,$$I=\begin{bmatrix}\vec\imath&\vec\jmath&\vec k\end{bmatrix}\implies I^2=\begin{bmatrix}\vec\imath\cdot\vec\imath&\vec\imath\cdot\vec\jmath&\vec\imath\cdot\vec k\\\vec\jmath\cdot\vec\imath&\vec\jmath\cdot\vec\jmath&\vec\jmath\cdot\vec k\\\vec k\cdot\vec\imath&\vec k\cdot\vec\jmath&\vec k\cdot\vec k\end{bmatrix}=I$$

Comment: I see, thanks!!